# Cocos2d background sound not playing a second time C++

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm using cocos2d-x on windows10 UWP project. I use the SimpleAudioEngine to load the music:

`CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance()->playBackgroundMusic("level_music1.wav",true);`

On the close button handler I use the end method:
`CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance()->end;`

When I run the debugger a second time I get these exceptions:

> Exception thrown at 0x765F3E28 (KernelBase.dll) in MiniGolf.exe: 0x000006BA: The RPC server is unavailable.
>   Exception thrown at 0x765F3E28 (KernelBase.dll) in MiniGolf.exe: 0x0000000E: Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.
>   Assert failed: getFileSize should be override by platform FileUtils
>   Assertion failed!

only if I rename the file to say like "level_music.wav" it works again but failed again the second time so I have to constantly rename it to work.

Answer (score 1):

this is an old bug which is fixed in cocos2d-x 3.10 and you can read more about it in [here](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/assert-attempting-to-play-audio-in-win8-1-project-on-windows10/25505/4):

the bug is caused by a missing getFileSize() method implementation in the winrt file.

to fixe the bug just download the last version of cocos2d-x or add the fixe code manually by yourself by going to cocos2d\cocos\platform\winrt then open up CCFileUtilsWinRT.h and add this method signature to CCFileUtilsWinRT class in the public section:

```
virtual long getFileSize(const std::string &filepath);
```

then in the same directery open up CCFileUtilsWinRT.cpp and add the method implementation like this:

```
long CCFileUtilsWinRT::getFileSize(const std::string &filepath)
{
    WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA fad;
    if (!GetFileAttributesEx(StringUtf8ToWideChar(filepath).c_str(), GetFileExInfoStandard, &fad))
    {
        return 0; // error condition, could call GetLastError to find out more
    }
    LARGE_INTEGER size;
    size.HighPart = fad.nFileSizeHigh;
    size.LowPart = fad.nFileSizeLow;
    return (long)size.QuadPart;
}
```